# Is wordpress 4.3 supported theme going to work in wordpress 4.5.3

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

[theme link is mentioned below](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/creative-portfolio-agency-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/11588854?ref=cirvitis)I downloaded a theme from envato which supporta version 4.3 or 4.2 it said it has composer which i cannot see. I  have already purchased it and I'm screwed now. What to do. No support no help

Comment: Almost themes require version wordpress exactly for working well. So you must update or download old version of wordpress theme require. This is best way xD

Comment: Ok but I hope there would not be any security issues with old version of wordpress